# Magento2 unable to create|use a virtual type

Tags: magento2, virtualtype

I'm trying to make use of a virtual type. I'm following the docs on this and everything should be pretty straight forward yet I'm kinda stuck.

This is what I have.

The class.

```
namespace Company\Extension\Model\Product\Attribute\Source;

class Test
{
    protected $string;

    public function __construct(String $test)
    {
        $this->string = $test;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return $this->string;
    }
}
```

The di.xml

```
<config>
    <virtualType name="TestVirtualType" type="Company\Extension\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">foo</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Now when running a simple php/bin magento

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]                                                            
  Invalid Document                                                                                            
  Element 'argument': The type definition is abstract.                                                        
  Line: 13                                                                                                    
  Internal error: xmlSchemaXPathProcessHistory, The state object to be removed is not the first in the list.  
  Line: 12                                                                                                    
  Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateChildElem, calling xmlRegExecPushString2().                                
  Line: 3                                                                                                     
  Internal error: xmlSchemaValidateElem, calling xmlSchemaStreamValidateChildElement().                       
  Line: 3                                                                                                     
  Internal error: xmlSchemaDocWalk, calling xmlSchemaValidateElem().                                          
  Line: 3
```

I'm following the docs on this as well as many provided examples. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help or pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I forgot this part

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this might have occured due to xmlns:xsi="//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

in the above line  "http:" is missing so please try adding that and your error will be resolved!!